# Best approach for association between three tables with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

First, sorry for my english.
Second, I'm not good at database modeling, so I might be completely wrong.

I'm writing a website (think of it as a forum), where in every post, each user can have a different roles.

The way I would do it without using entity framework is creating 3 tables:

- User
- Group
- Role
- UserGroupRole

Where UserGroupRole would contain the keys for the 3 tables.

How can I do it with entity framework?

Maybe the whole aproach is incorrect, I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain more? What is the difference between `Group` and `Role`? Is a `User` in *many* groups or only in *one* group? Is there a relationship between `Group` and `Role`? And if yes, which one: many-to-many or one-to-many or...?

Comment: Sure. A user can be in 0-N Groups, and in each of these groups can have 1 rol. For example, User "didacpunyet" is role "admin" in group "didac's", and User "didacpunyet" is "member" in "Slauma's"

Comment: The best approache I found so far is to have 2 entities and a relation. That would be User and GroupRole, and a 1-N relationship between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would probably also work with 4 entities and tables. In EF 4.1 something along these lines:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserGroupRole> UserGroupRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserGroupRole> UserGroupRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserGroupRole> UserGroupRoles { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroupRole
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }   // FK property
    [Key]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }  // FK property
    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }   // FK property

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

The foreign key properties enforce all three relationships to be required (`null` is not allowed) and the complex key over all three Ids ensure that any combination of user, group and role can only exist once. You can remove some of the navigation collections - for example in `Group` and `Role` - if you don't need them.

Comment: Ok I understand that solution but I'm not sure how to do it. I would rather use the visual desginer since this is my very first project with EF. Here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/94/enies.png/ is a screenshot of the diagram (don't mind the existing associations). Could you please explain me how to create the asociations between PlayerGroupRole.Player - Player.Id, PlayerGroupRole.Group - Group.Id, and PlayerGroupRole.Role - Role.Id ?

Comment: @Dídac: As far as I know: When you click with the right mouse button on the designer surface, you'll find an option "Add -> Association" (or similar). Then in the dialog you define both ends of the relationship: entities, multiplicities, if you want navigation properties on both sides and if you want to add foreign key properties (recommended).